# How to validate just one field for register a user for spring project with hibernate validator?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

```
<input name="id" placeholder="input your id"/>
<button id="id_check">check</button>
<input name="password" placeholder="input your id"/>
<input type="submit" value="register" />
```

Currently, I uses a controller for user.
Controller code following...

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("...")
    public String registerForm(...) { ... }

    @PostMapping("...")
    public String register(@ModelAttribute @Validated ...) { ... }

    .....
}
```

I want to check `id` using ajax call.

For id duplication check, can I use hibernate validator? (**for one field. not submit action**) Also it should be validate duplication of id.(using `dao`).
For example, one field for validation should be checked duplication and validated by hibernate validator(`@NotEmpty`, `@Email`...)

Comment: You want to check whether userId is already present in respective table.?Before form submission

Comment: yes. when the field need to be validated, it should be checked whether it is dupliated or not. and `@NotEmpty` validator etc.(*not manually programmatically*)

Comment: have alook at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613055/hibernate-unique-key-validation

Comment: @TahirHussainMir thanks. What do you think of the way?

Comment: Ok.. On ajax request you want check it. I can give u suggestion for finding duplicate or not.