# Existing client validation in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a Rest API and I need to validate that the client already exists at the time of registration, using the CPF as the key.

This is my Post method on the controller:

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Client> save(@Valid @RequestBody Client client) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.clientService.save(client));
    }
```

This is my Client class:

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be empty")
    private String name;

    @CPF
    @Size(min = 0, max = 11)
    private String cpf;
```

I have no idea how to perform the validation on my controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already exists where? In a DB?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best way, but my first guess would be to add a `@Column(unique=true)` where you define `DTO`, that will throw error during `save`.

Another longer but probably more transparent way to do it, is defining your own [validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423955/4457451).

Upd.
You didn't mention initially that you are using MongoDB.
So what you need is to change your `Client` class like so:

```
@Document
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client{
same as before
....

@CPF
@Indexed(unique=true)
@Size(min = 0, max = 11)
private String cpf;
```

`@Indexed(unique=true)` Let's MongoDB know that this field must be unique.
That's it. Make sure that you have index in the DB itself as well.

Comment: Is it possible to be directly in the Post method in the controller? Making a query in the repository using the CPF as key.